# iPhone SQLite table inconsistency

Tags: ios, iphone, database, sqlite, sdk

I have an sqlite table that shows scores from different game modes.  In one of the columns, I don't want the score to show up unless the user reaches the final 5th level, but I also don't want it to be recorded as a 0 either. I want it to be as if the game was never played.  No score recorded at all.  Here's what I have....

```
 if(appDelegate.easymediumhard == 2 && gameVarLevel == 5){

            if(gameVarLevel == 5){
            globalScore = timeSeconds;
            }
else if(gameVarLevel != 5){
    ????????????
    }

        }
```

Now I know i need the else if statement but I don't know what it should be.

Comment: I don't understand.  Why don't you just not write the score to the table?

Comment: In fact, you will never get to the else statement.  A requirement to get to the inner code is that gameVarLevel == 5.  If so, you will never hit the ???????? part.

Comment: i need the score to be written to the DB when level 5 is completed but not if level 5 isn't completed

Comment: Ditto on what Mark said.  We need some more context here.  What you probably want to do is to move the write to the table to inside of your if statement.

Comment: @NextRev: Your code as shown never writes to the database at all. Either you've forgotten to post some code, or your problem is already solved.

Comment: it gets written to the database in another .m file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to move your table write to inside the `if` statement.  I would assume it currently comes at some point after, but I don't know because you didn't post that part.

**Edit:**

If your write is in a different part of your program as you say, then you either need a separate variable to track a valid score, i.e. `bool scoreValid`, or you need to set your score to something you know is not valid, such as -1 for instance.

Then in the code that writes the table, check if the score is valid, and only write if it is.

For instance, your code would be such:

```
if(appDelegate.easymediumhard == 2 && gameVarLevel == 5){

       globalScore = timeSeconds;
       scoreValid = YES;

} else {

      scoreValid = NO;

}
```

I am making a bunch of assumptions cause I don't know your real requirements for a valid score, but that is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

don't do anything in the else. don't even have an else.

Comment: it automatically gets set to a zero if i don't write the else

Comment: I would assume globalScore would be undefined in that case or a default value set before the 'if' statment.

Comment: I thought that's what he wanted